# how do you capture text between first occurance of [ and last occurence of ] in R

Tags: r, regex

I need to extrack text between [],

I have this:

```
x <- "corp_applicaiton[CORP_webapp1][1]"
```

I need to capture this text:

```
CORP_webapp1][1
```

then replace all special characters with under score:

I've tried this:

```
str_match(x, ".*\\[(.*?)].*")[,2]
```

but this outputs:

```
1
```

any ideas?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I want to optain "CORP_webapp1__1"

Comment: Try `str_extract` and then `str_replace`.

Comment: How about this regex `(?:\\[).*(?:\\])`

Comment: Did anything work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regular expressions.

```
x<-c("corp_applicaiton[CORP_webapp1][1]")
x2 = sub(".*?\\[(.*)\\].*", "\\1", x)
gsub("\\W", "_", x2)
[1] "CORP_webapp1__1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.+\[(.+)\]\[(.+)\]
```

replace with
$1_$2

https://regex101.com/r/3BNz8j/1

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve what you need with a single [`gsubfn`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html) but still it requires 2 regular expressions:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> x<-c("corp_applicaiton[CORP_webapp1][1]")
> gsubfn("^[^[]*\\[(.*)].*$", function(m) gsub("\\W", "_", m), x)
[1] "CORP_webapp1__1"
```

It will look for the following pattern:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^[]*` - 0+ chars other than `[`
- `\\[` - a literal `[`
- `(.*)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last...
- `]` - literal `]`
- `.*` - and any 0+ chars up to the string end.

Then, the nested callback function with `gsub("\\W", "_", m)` inside will replace each non-word char `(\W`) with a `_` in the Group 1 value, and will only return that value.